# Call variable correct and display PHP generated HTML in the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m creating a plugin called woomps. In the main php file i do a calculation when template redirect.

```
add_action('template_redirect','woomps_loop');
```

This calculates x: (it’s actually a big calculation).

```
function woomps_loop() {
$x = 10;
Return $x
}
```

I want to show this variable based on a shortcode. Therefore, in my main php file I include the frontend.php through this code.

```
    function woomps_scripts() {
    include 'frontend.php'; 
}
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','woomps_scripts');
```

Where the frontend.php has this code

```
    function woomps_subscription_slider (){
    //How do I call the variable from woomps_loop() without running all the code again.
    echo "<div>\n";
    echo "<p>\n"; 
    echo $x; 
    echo "</p>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
add_shortcode("woomps-subscription-slider", "woomps_subscription_slider");
```

The shortcode is added to one of my pages so it displays, but……

---

1. **How do I call the `$x` variable form `woomps_loop()` without running the code again?**
2. **This `<div>` will come before all other content generated in `the_content()`. Why is that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $x; //Had to define it global before setting it, i dident understand this before @cameronjonesweb exmample.
$x = $total_qty;
```

Then reference it like this:

```
function woomps_subscription_slider ($x){
global $x_subs;
$content = <<<EOD
<div>
<p>
{$x_subs}
</p>
</div>
EOD;

return $content;
} //end woomps_subscription_slider
```

It worked. Try this `EOD` to `return` multiple lines of HTML, and it does get placed inside `the_content()` loop

2. Okay. Thank you!

Comment: switch out $x_subs with $x. Maybe i shouldent answer my own questions :| new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

1) Store it as a global variable. So change your `woomps_loop` function to

```
global $x;

function woomps_loop() {
    global $x;
    $x = 10;
    return $x
}
```

(PS you probably won't need to return `$x` here now)
Then also define `$x` in your shortcode function

```
function woomps_subscription_slider (){
    global $x;
    echo "<div>\n";
    //... rest of it carries on
```

2) Because you're `echo`ing. Return the value instead.